# NDK - extending a class and using a pointer to an array causes segfault

Tags: c, pointers, crash, android-ndk

//My structure / class

```
class ImgObj{
public:
    unsigned int *textu; //image
};
```

// My general object with basic functions

```
class Aobj {
  protected:
    ImgObj *_obj;    
  public:

    Aobj();
    virtual ~Aobj();

    ImgObj *getB(int p);
    void add(unsigned int *texture);
};

//Here a create an array of that structure

void Aobj::setFrameCount(int q) {
    _obj = new ImgObj[q];
}

//Adding it

void Aobj::add(unsigned int *texture, int size)
{
counter++;   (counter is 0, I didn't specify this but it is there)
_obj[counter-1].textu = (unsigned int *)malloc(size);
_obj[counter-1].textu = texture;
}


 // Getting back the buffer 

ImgObj *Aobj::getB(int p) {
return &_obj[p];
}


//Extending the main object with some other functions which are not present here

class Background : public Aobj {
public:
    Background();
    virtual ~Background();

};
```

//---------------------------------

// My MAIN test
// I'm basically trying to assign the image and after assigning the second time in a loop
// it crashes

```
Main::Main()
{
    // image bytes 11704 -> 77w * 38h * 4


            unsigned int *texture = new unsigned int[11704];  //an example
            //Now imagine I'm filling this array with an image...
            int size = 11704;

            Background *background = new Background;

            background->setFrameCount(1);
            background->add(texture, size);


            unsigned int *testtex; //testing

            while(true)
            {

             testtex = background->getB(0)->textu;  

             } 
            // When using this it crashes (the first time works fine, the second time crash)
     }
```

Comment: new user tip: and where is the question? Do you expect some answer, or just want "someone to do something" with it ? :)

Comment: As I said in the answer: I want to know why it crashes and possible fixes, if I'm doing something wrong with the allocation or reading the the info from the pointer to display an image, what would be the fix? thank you . I think now the code has everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
_obj[counter-1].textu = (unsigned int *)malloc(size);
_obj[counter-1].textu = texture;
```

1st line will allocate memory of size `size`: what is `size`?
2nd line will override pointer to the newly allocated memory and replace the pointer: you probably wanted to copy the contents of the memory `texture` points to.

Comment: Size is the size in unsigned int of the image. After passing size it will allocate the space and then I'm assigning the image. 

If you can propose a code resolution because I'm not quite sure what's your solution. I don't see the problem here. It used to work and then it is no more working. How whould I write this piece of code? (if that is the error)

Comment: you don't assign the image -- you have the image in memory and a pointer to the location in the memory (`texture`) and you either want to store the pointer to this location in `_obj[counter-1].textu` or you want to copy the image to a new location in memory and save a pointer to that location in `_obj[counter-1].textu` -- I can't tell from the provided code. In the first case you can drop the 1st line completely, in the second case you need to copy the image to the new location.

Comment: Ok, I want to store this array **texture** into **_obj[counter-1].textu** , simple . How do you do that? knowing that **texture** is always a new image with a new size and will be stored inside this array. thanks

Comment: Well it's not *that* simple I'm afraid. See: you cannot store "this array texture" in `textu` as this is just an pointer. In a pointer you store the memory address of the beginning of an object. Note that arrays are more or less syntactic sugar for pointers. Now if all you want to do is to store the pointer to the existing image, then just drop the first line. But I don't know anything about the livetime of image. I think you'll need to understand the whole pointer-concept and if that doesn't help you'll need to provide a more complete example.

Comment: So you are saying by passing that array of int I'm not actaully passing the content but I'm only passing the memory address??? I thought I was passing a value , that is an array not a pointer (that's my understanding).  If that is not the case should I go get the value from the pointer and copy pixel x pixel? I hope not otherwise what's memcpy for ?

Comment: That is one of the options. I don't know about the life-time of the object you're pointing to. You may need to copy the contents of the memory (yes, memcpy) if the image gets deleted elsewhere. Otherwise just setting pointer1 = pointer2 is fine. But I can't tell that from the code you provided and those two lines where the only ones that got my attention.

Comment: ok the texture I pass to the background is something I get from the jni call from java then I'd like to pass that to the ndk. I don't want to load the resource from the res.manager. So what I do is passing the byte array (an object that I re cast) which works fine, I see the memory dump, its there.
Knowing that, How would you set this array. What would be the right BASIC STEP that I'm probably missing :) .

Comment: -> Basic steps to allocate memory and set uint. An example would be nice, like in my example I create the array test and I want to add this array of ** (unsigned *int) **

Comment: Thanks for checking by the way, I found the solution.

Comment: Good for you! Would be nice if you add the solution to the question, so ppl who see this don't need to ask again

Comment: If people learn how to behave I will be open to share. If they keep giving you bad votes for each question they don't know the response!

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted you, but I only didn't because you were new here. Your question was put very unclear, or better said there wasn't a clear question. Revealing the answer after you asked here and took the time of peoples should be a matter of course. The question doesn't disappear from the internet just because you're no more interested in it. Just think about the next person who has the same problem and finds this thread. She'll be very annoyed!